# Alert dialog to confirm a Cancel action

Tags: wording, confirmation, dialog

I have an application from which you can run different step by step wizards. It has a **Cancel** button at the top, which allows the user to quit the current wizard.

I have a dialog that appears on tapping Cancel to confirm that the user really wants to Cancel the current wizard and lose their changes.

On a dialog like this there is a negative and positive action and usually the negative action is worded Cancel.

**E.g. A log out dialog would be** - *Are you sure you want to log out? [Cancel, Log out]* where Cancel closes the dialog and doesn't log out.

However, the issue for me is my positive action is actually Cancel. I need an option that closes the dialog and ignores the wizard Cancel and an option that confirms that the user actually wants to Cancel.

**What wording should I use?**

Comment: You should use a question like "Are you sure you want to Cancel and lose your changes?" **[Yes] [No]** and not have a button on the confirmation which is labelled Cancel at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not recommendable to use the word Cancel in pop-up/alert boxes.
You could use another wording like **close** or **quit**. You have several good combinations for the buttons, here is just one (for example, you could change Cancel for "No, stay"):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6wyhk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

---

In the case you decide to use it, **you have to be wordy**. E.g:

[image]